# Kubernetes-Mesos: building problems

Tags: kubernetes, mesos, kubernetes-mesos

I am following the instructions on: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos/#deploy-kubernetes-mesos

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
cd kubernetes
export KUBERNETES_CONTRIB=mesos
make



-bash-4.2$ pwd
~/kubernetes
-bash-4.2$ ls
api                 contrib          federation  Makefile                  release
build               CONTRIB.md       Godeps      Makefile.generated_files  test
CHANGELOG.md        CONTRIBUTING.md  hack        _output                   third_party
cluster             DESIGN.md        hooks       pkg                       Vagrantfile
cmd                 docs             LICENSE     plugin                    vendor
code-of-conduct.md  examples         logo        README.md                 www
-bash-4.2$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `/*.go', needed by `_output/bin/deepcopy-gen'.  Stop.
```

Do I need to do something before `make` or something?